# error in including validation in struts.xml file in jdeveloper

Tags: struts

I am developing my first application in jDeveloper using struts framework . kindly help i want to implement validations on my login.jsp. I have created a validation.xml file but it displays error when i include in my struts.xml file.this is a part of source code of `struts.xml` file:

```
<action path="/login" type="coorpportal.LoginAction" validate="true">
  <result name ="input" path="/login.jsp"/>
  <forward name="fail" path="/login.jsp"/>
  <forward name="success" path="/welcome.do"/>
```

// error is=Element result not expected
kindly guide me.

Comment: You have invalid config, make sure the jdeveloper is able to validate it against doctype.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different versions of Struts.

- `<forward>` is Struts 1
- `<result>` is Struts 2

Decide which version you're using and use only that version's configuration elements.